# OpenAPI does not scan external libraries?

Tags: openapi, microprofile

I am building a microservice with eclipse-microprofile 3 and I am using openapi.
Services and XMLRoot classes defined directly in my service are published to openapi (as expected). But my service includes also additional jar files located under /WEB-INF/lib. These jar files are not scanned by open api.

```
- MyXMLRootClass.java   // scanned
- MyRestSerivce.java    // scanned
- WEB-INF/
  |- my-lib.jar         // ignored
```

How can I tell OpenAPI to scann also external jar files?

See also my example project setup [here](https://github.com/rsoika/glassfish-issue-22822)

Comment: What tool/framework do you use? OpenAPI is a specification not a tool.

Comment: I am running a payara jarkata-ee server v5.201

Comment: I added an example application